# Is ModSecurity 2.9 able to perform censorship ? (change the response body)

Tags: apache, mod-security

I would like to know if ModSecurity is able to perform censorhip.

For example, the response of the application is:

{"error": null,
"id": "1",
"result": [ { "name": "fly", "class": "insect" }, { "name": "spider", "class": "arachnid"} ]
}

And we would like send the following response, without the "spider" part, to the client:

{"error": null,
"id": "1",
"result": [ { "name": "fly", "class": "insect" } ]
}

We need this because the editor of the application is not able to perform such response with some filter in the request for example.

I cannot find any information to know if it is possible, and if so how it can be done.

So I've tried with a rule like ...

---

```
SecRule RESPONSE_BODY "@rx .*" "id:100,phase:4,exec:/usr/local/bin/change-response-body.lua,allow"
```

---

... and a change-response-body.lua script like:

---

```
#!/usr/bin/lua
function main()

local respBody = m.getvar("RESPONSE_BODY")

-- some parsing on respBody

respBody = "just a try"

m.setenv("RESPONSE_BODY", respBody)
m.setvar("RESPONSE_BODY", respBody )

return 1
end
```

---

And it does not work.

Can you tell help me on that please ?

Thanks in advance.

Spin

Comment: Hi, ModSecurity  is primarily designed for web app security. but it excels in filtering and blocking malicious traffic/websites, so it can do some censorship. indirectly

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do it by applying action [@rsub](https://github.com/owasp-modsecurity/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-(v2.x)#user-content-rsub) to [STREAM_OUTPUT_BODY](https://github.com/owasp-modsecurity/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-(v2.x)#stream_output_body) variable. For this to work, you need to set ModSecurity directives `SecStreamOutBodyInspection` and `SecContentInjection` to `On` (which may have negative impact on performance, read the docs).

Comment: Thanks azurit, I managed to make it work partially. However I'm not able to user backreferences in my substitution, I don't know the syntax to use.

Comment: For example to return "f1": [], I tried many syntax like with $2:
--- 
   SecRule STREAM_OUTPUT_BODY '@rsub s/"f1": \[(.*)\](.*)"f2": "v2"/"f1": []$2"f2": "v2"/' "phase:4,id:172,t:none,nolog,pass"
--- 
I also tried {2}, \2, \(2\) etc... with no luck. Do you know if it's possible and how ?

Comment: Not sure what you want to do. If i take the example from your question, this should work: SecRule STREAM_OUTPUT_BODY '@rsub s/(?:, )?{ "name": "spider", "class": "arachnid"}//' "phase:4,id:172,t:none,nolog,pass"

Comment: Thanks Azurit, it works this way. I'll post another question for a more complex case.